# Selecting from multiple variables

Tags: python, sikuli

I am attempting to find objects on the screen, see if they exist, and if so, select them. Using the Sikuli library to run this little automation.

```
while True:
    if exist("image/one.png", "image/two.png", "image/three.png"):
        click ("image/one.png", or "image/two.png", or "image/three.png")
    break
```

I get `SyntaxError: mismatched input 'or' expecting RPAREN`a I've done a quick search but there is nothing I saw relevant to my particular issue.

I've even tried

```
while True:
        if exist("image/one.png", or "image/two.png", or "image/three.png"):
            click ("image/one.png", or "image/two.png", or "image/three.png")
        break
```

And that results in the same error.

@Stephan: New code snippet with error.

```
class gameImages():
    imageFiles = ["one.png", "two.png", "three,png"]

for imageFile in imageFiles:
    if exists(imageFile):
        click(imageFile)
```

The Error now, :

```
NameError: name 'imageFiles' is not defined
```

Comment: Why are you putting those `or`s in? You can't put an `or` like that after a comma. What example are you working from?

Comment: What if you replace the `or`s with `|`?

Comment: @DavidRobinson I saw that done before, don't recall where. Are you saying remove the comma and it should function?

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos I gave that a shot too. Exact same error

Comment: @Dave: no. Without the comma, `"image/one.png" or "image/two.png" or "image/three.png"` will *always* evaluate to `"image/one.png"`, and will do so before it is given to the `click` function at all.

Comment: @Dave: I take it that what you are trying to do is to get it to click whichever of them exists?

Comment: @Dave: Also, where your `break` statement currently is, it will *always* break after running the loop just once (making the loop unnecessary). Perhaps you meant to put `break` inside the if statement?

Comment: @DavidRobinson Correct. I am trying to select any of the .png's that do exist. And removing the comma now runs the script, but, throws `NameError: name 'exist' is not defined`

Comment: Do you mean `exists`?

Comment: Wow, thats an awesome error!

Comment: Plus, I thought or was the same meaning as and/or ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for imageFile in imageFiles:
  if exists(imageFile):
    click(imageFile)
```

Your `while` loop isn't doing anything, and neither is your `break` statement.  This might do what you want, assuming I understand what you want to do.

Comment: Get `SyntaxError: no viable alternative at input 'if'`

Comment: @Dave did you setup imageFiles with a list of your image files? also did you copy my code exactly? that error implies a syntax problem

Comment: I did, must have had wrong. Copied again. I have `NameError: name 'imageFiles' is not defined` I created a list `imageFiles = ["x", "x", "x"]` So not sure why I am getting not defined.

Comment: @Dave check to make sure imageFiles is spelled the same way and within the scope of where you wrote that for loop

Comment: See above original question, at bottom.

Comment: @Dave you forgot to pluralize it. Also make your class something different.

Comment: Made changes. Back to `not defined` See above.

Comment: Worked today. I guess it didn't like me yesterday. /shrug/

Answer (score 0):

Even easier, this is a perfect use of filter(ifexist,imageFiles). You then know that all >=0 elements in the return of filter can be used :). And it's more concise and clearly conveys your intent - much nicer to read then a chain of for's and if's

```
a = range(10)
# [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

print filter(lambda x: x > 5, a)
# [6,7,8,9]
```

Also the or is a logical operator:

e.g.

```
a = 5
b = 6
c = 5

if( (a==c) or (b==c) ):
    print 'c is repeated'

# c is repeated
```

your use of the or here makes no sense as it doesn't have operands to operate on - these can even be two objects, e.g.

1 or 2 since [anything](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/truth.html) can be cast to a boolean

a concise way to do what you want is:
//imagepaths = your list of imagepaths

```
map(lambda x: click(x.getTarget()), filter(exists, imagepaths))
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading a little of the Sikuli docs, I think this *might* also do what you want.

```
for impath in ("image/one.png", "image/two.png", "image/three.png"):
    match = exists(impath)
    if match:
        click(match.getTarget())
```

Comment: This is abit out of my bounds to say, but I think that error which mentions a whole lotta Java, might be a problem with the library itself. If the code was wrong you should have gotten a familiar Python traceback. But on the other hand, I may just be speaking in my own defense :)

Comment: ...ok, so sikuli uses Jython, that explains that. Although I couldn't tell you what the error meant as I don't know Java or if that is a normal Jython error message.